# How to configure the ColdFusion Eclipse debugger

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9, coldfusionbuilder

I'm running the ColdFusion Builder 3 (Express edition) to connect to a locally running ColdFusion 9 server (windows machine).

When I set up the RDS configuration on the CF Builder and click on **Test Connection**  everything is ok.

[image: RDS Configuration Settings]

But when I click on **Test Debugger** I get the following error:

> Could not initialize class coldfusion.log.CFLogs

[image: RDS Error message]

Is this a problem with CF Builder 3 trying to access the CF 9 server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this Adobe forum post](https://forums.adobe.com/message/3903632#3903632) they resolved the same issue by changing the port setting in ColdFusion Builder to the standard HTTP port (normally 80).

I also found [this article](http://rich-blog.blogspot.com/2012/01/howto-coldfusion-debugger.html) which details the steps to setup ColdFusion  debugging with Eclipse and it also has the port assigned to 80.

**UPDATE:**

Read this how-to article from Charlie Arehart. While it references older versions I think the same steps still apply and he mentions specific things that must be enabled on your ColdFusion server for it to work. Hope that helps.

[Setting up ColdFusion Builder Step Debugging](http://www.carehart.org/presentations/setting_up_coldfusion_builder_step_debugging.pdf)

And here is a video tutorial from Adobe's blog that steps you through the process as well.

[Learn how to debug ColdFusion applications using ColdFusion Builder](http://blogs.adobe.com/anand/2011/01/learn-how-to-debug-coldfusion-applications-using-coldfusion-builder-2.html)

Comment: What messages/errors do you see in the ColdFusion log file?  `C:\ColdFusion\ColdFusion9\logs`

Comment: Have you tried configuring the CF Builder debug port to `52000` (instead of `56815` as in your original question)?

Comment: Never mind my last comment. That RDS port needs to be your HTTP port as I specified in my answer (80). I have added another resource to my answer from Charlie Arehart. Please read that information on how to setup debugging.

Comment: Yes, the article from Charlie Arehart was the solution(but please keep the other link as well :) Thanks alot!!!